# How to read database files which are stored in another directory outside the project root in .NET

Tags: asp.net, .net, sql-server, ms-access

Does anyone know how can I read from another directory located outside the project root (let's say `C:\Users\User\Desktop\databases_directory`) and migrate those database files to my project SQL Server database (assume that the project is located at `C:\Users\User\Desktop\MyAspProject`)?

Also, the database files which are stored in that directory are MS Access.

Comment: So you're asking how to convert an MS Access `.mdb` or `.accdb` file to a SQL Server database? That's not really doable automatically...

Comment: ..and why are you using Access at all when you have SQL Server?

Comment: I have another app which generates and exports MS Access database files, and for x reasons I cannot modify and encounter with that app. The data from those databases is needed in a .NET app, but the real problem is that the other app generates those databases on a daily basis and populates them, which means I cannot just import those in SQL server once because for each day a new db is created , which will correspond to only one table in my SQL server database

Comment: Use SSIS to create a data import process you can automate, I guess…

Comment: Unless you have very good reason, do NOT store each day's output in a new table. Instead use one table with an additional date field to identify each output.

Comment: @Applecore yes, that is exactly the whole point. One table in SQL server database which will be populated each time from different databases which are generated on a daily basis and populated on an hourly basis in MS access. Bu how do I read from that directory and store the data ?

Answer (score 1):

if the access data files are just say one mdb or one accDB file, and each mdb/accDB file has say one table, then you certainly can open such files, read the one table and say append data to a existing sql server table.

If the access database files are a complex database with related data such as many tables with a child table, and primary keys, and the child tables having foreign keys, then that not some simple tasks. So, simple data table inside the access file, then yes, but multiple related tables, then this becomes not some data table read, but a rather complex issue.

but, sure, you can certainly open + read those files, and the files don't have to be in the root folder on that web server, but they do have to be files that can be directly read/used/opened by the web server. (so, NOT SOME folder on the user's computer).

If we are talking about end user files, then they would have to up-load them to the server.

So, with above in mind?

Let's assume we have several accDB files in that desktop folder on the web server. (Again, BEYOND IMPORANT here, we are talking about a folder on the web server, NOT THE END users computer).

You will ALSO have to ensure that on this running web server, that ms-access is installed, or at the very least, the ms-access data engine. You also have to ensure that the bit size of the ms-access installed on that web server matches the bit size the asp.net project is running as (x32 bits, or x64 bits). You MUST deal with this bit size issued, since .net code can run as either x32 bits, or x64 bits, but the access database system being a NON .net, or what we call un-managed code? It can ONLY be used/consumed/interacted with from the SAME bit size process running in .net.

So, there is BOATLOADS of issues here, and all of them have to be dealt with you.

Ok, now, with all of the above, let's assume that there is some accDB data files in a folder on the desktop (but again, this desktop folder is running on the web server  - not the users end computer). If such files are on the user computer, then of course the web server cannot reach out and grab such files. User's files are of course 100% hands off (else when you visit my web site to view a cute cat picture, I would then start rumanaging around on your computer - grab some files and folders called banking! Or some files called my-passwords!!!). If you could from a web site reach out to files on computer, then no one with a sane working brain would EVER use the internet again, right?).

So, code to get the list of files in that folder, and then read the data from each access file and add the rows of data to a table in sql server will look like this:

Let's build a bit of a UI. The folder name, and then a grid of the files.

So, this markup:

```
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtFolder" runat="server" Width="556px"
            Text="C:\Users\Kalla\Desktop\datafiles\"
            ></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:Button ID="cmdLoad" runat="server" 
            Text="Load Files" CssClass="btn"
            style="margin-left:20px"
            OnClick="cmdLoad_Click"
         />

        <br />
        <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" Width="40%" CssClass="table">
            <Columns>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Select" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
                    <ItemTemplate >
                        <asp:CheckBox ID="chkSel" runat="server" />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
        <p style="font-size:large;font:bold">Select from above files to import to SQL server</p>
        <asp:Button ID="cmdImport" runat="server" Text="Import to SQL Server" CssClass="btn" />

        <br />
        <br />
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" />
        <br />
```

Ok, now code to load up the files for selection.

This code:

```
Protected Sub cmdLoad_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)

    Dim rstFiles As New DataTable
    rstFiles.Columns.Add("DataFile")
    rstFiles.Columns.Add("Created", GetType(DateTime))
    rstFiles.Columns.Add("ImportedRows", GetType(DateTime))

    Dim MyFolder As New DirectoryInfo(txtFolder.Text)

    Dim MyFileList() As FileInfo = MyFolder.GetFiles("*.accDB")

    For Each OneFile As FileInfo In MyFileList
        Dim OneRow As DataRow = rstFiles.NewRow
        OneRow("DataFile") = OneFile.Name
        OneRow("Created") = OneFile.CreationTime.ToString("G")
        rstFiles.Rows.Add(OneRow)
    Next

    GridView1.DataSource = rstFiles
    GridView1.DataBind()

End Sub
```

and when we run, we have this:

[image]

And now the import button code.

That looks like this:

```
Protected Sub cmdImport_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cmdImport.Click

    ' Process each selected file

    For Each gRow As GridViewRow In GridView1.Rows

        Dim ckBox As CheckBox = gRow.FindControl("chkSel")

        If ckBox.Checked Then
            Dim sFile = gRow.Cells(1).Text

            ' import this one data file
            Dim RowsImported As Integer = ImportData(sFile)
            gRow.Cells(3).Text = RowsImported

        End If

    Next


End Sub

Function ImportData(sFile) As Integer

    ' access connection
    Dim sAccessCon As String =
       $"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source={txtFolder.Text + sFile}"

    Dim strSQL As String =
        "SELECT * FROM tblHotelsA"

    Dim rstInData As DataTable = MyRstACC(strSQL, sAccessCon)

    ' now open SQL server table
    strSQL = "SELECT * FROM tblhotelsA WHERE ID = 0"

    Dim RowCount As Integer = 0

    Dim rstSQLServer As New DataTable
    Using conn As New SqlConnection(My.Settings.TESTA)
        Using cmdSQL As New SqlCommand(strSQL, conn)
            conn.Open()
            rstSQLServer.Load(cmdSQL.ExecuteReader)

            RowCount = rstInData.Rows.Count

            For Each FromRow As DataRow In rstInData.Rows
                Dim SQLRow As DataRow = rstSQLServer.NewRow
                For i = 1 To rstInData.Columns.Count - 1 ' start at 1, not 0 to skip PK
                    SQLRow(i) = FromRow(i)
                Next
                rstSQLServer.Rows.Add(SQLRow)
            Next

            ' save data to sql server
            Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter(cmdSQL)
            Dim daU As New SqlCommandBuilder(da)
            da.Update(rstSQLServer)

        End Using
    End Using

    Return RowCount

End Function
```

And thus, we see this after importing

[image]

And I did (to save some keyboards, use these two helpers)

```
Public Function MyRstACC(strSQL As String, strCon As String) As DataTable

    Dim rstData As New DataTable
    Using conn As New OleDbConnection(strCon)
        Using cmdSQL As New OleDbCommand(strSQL, conn)
            conn.Open()
            rstData.Load(cmdSQL.ExecuteReader)
        End Using
    End Using

    Return rstData

End Function
```

Now, in above, I assumed that the columns from the tables are the same, and in the same order.

A bit more tweaking if they are not to be in the same order.

On the other hand, if each table has a different data structure, then of course we now have a complex migration and field mapping challenge here.